# Ackermann function in raptor

Tags: function, ackermann, raptor

How does one create ackermann function using Raptor flowchart? Can it be done? I have a general idea, but i have no idea how to write function 2 or 3 a(m-1,1) or a(m-1, a(m,n-1).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the recursive Ackermann function to an iterative one. This [PDF](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/analyst/backiss/IA21.pdf) explains how to do it. Then just model the iterative one with Raptor.